# Why Did I Get a "Great Answer" Badge for a CW Answer?

Tags: support, badges, community-wiki, canonical-questions

I posted ["What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net/4660186#4660186) as a place for canonical answers to this canonical question. In fact, most of the answers here are not from me.

Why in the world did this earn me a Gold badge? I explicitly made it CW so that I would neither gain rep nor badges.

Comment: CW status does not affect badges.

Comment: What wrong with badges? Anyway the only way to have a post not give you anything is to disassociate it from your account. I remember seeing here on Meta that it's possible to flag your own post and ask for such disassociation.

Comment: You don't even have to write the answer yourself to get a badge. I got a Necromaner badge for [copying a comment to a CW answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12980627/597607). Not fair at all.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the description of Great Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/67399#67399):

> Earn a score of 100 on one answer

Since 'score' is up‌**votes** less down‌**votes**, and your post has undoubtedly received **votes** (although Community Wiki means that those don't translate into *rep*), the post is eligible for the badge.

Comment: It seems wrong.

Comment: @JohnSaunders *Why?*

Comment: @EliahKagan: did you look at that question? It's not a question of mine, and it's answered by many people. Why am _i_ the one to get the gold badge?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I did read your question. That argument is not really clear in it. I also disagree with that argument--you created an answer that others were able to expand and make better, and you deserve credit for that. *People* deserve to know you did it, even if you don't want credit. Badges provide credit even in cases where it doesn't make sense for you to get rep, like this one. However, you may want to make this clearer in your question (though you might not want to bother, as this has been duped, it's your choice). It's a valuable argument and others might agree with it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Also, is your intention to post a feature request? This was probably duped because you were asking *why*, but if your intention is to say it *should* be this way, that might not be considered a duplicate. (Your question is tagged [meta-tag:support] and not [meta-tag:bug] or [meta-tag:feature-request].)